# Apache Nutch 1.x injection crawldb error

Tags: apache, nutch

Have tried googling the issue but can't find anything useful.

Following tutorial in https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Verified nutch with bin/nutch and it is fine

Have java 8 installed

```
java -version returns
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And included in path uxing export

```
export JAVA_HOME="/cygdrive/c/program files/java/jre8"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Note using windows hence using cygwin64 as well.

Have added directory urls and added file seed.txt with one url

The ran

```
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls/seed.txt
```

and then gets the following error:

> Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
>   Injector: urlDir: urls/seed.txt
>   Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
>   Injector: java.io.IOException: lock file crawl/crawldb/.locked already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Hi There are two parts in this problem :

1 . There is already .locked file present in crawldb folder . Just delete the .locked file.

2 . Set the System environment variable Path for both `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` then also set the User environment variable with `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%HADOOP_HOME%` without bin.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: another Nutch job holds a lock on the CrawlDb resp. it crashed or was killed before the lock file has been removed after the job has succeeded. Deleting the lock file `crawl/crawldb/.locked` should solve the problem. But it's also good practice to look into log files (esp. the hadoop.log) to find out the reason why the lock file hasn't been removed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Checked hadoop.log and it was to winutils.exe missing.                                                          2018-06-04 13:50:13,869 ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

Comment: Could you inform the best place to get this winutils.exe

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Have downloaded from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils and copied the folder 'hadoop-2.8.3/bin' to c:\pf\hadoop281. Then added this to the windows PATH environment and included export HADOOP_HOME="/cygdrive/c/pf/hadoop281" then export PATH="$HADOOP_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH". But still getting error 2018-06-07 15:12:44,391 ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries. Is the null in null\bin\winutils.exe imply some variable is not set?

Comment: Also from github.com/steveloughran/winutils how can one tell which version of the version of the hadoop bin is the correct one of the one nutch 1.14 is compiled to?

Comment: The full path to the executable is `c:\pf\hadoop281\bin\winutils.exe`? Did you try both variants to set the Hadoop home dir described in https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems?